# Как на Python список разделить по 3 элемента

Tags: python, список

Есть список из следующих элементов:

```
sp = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Как разделить список по 3 элементам, чтобы при обращении sp[0] и sp[1] выдавало:

```
sp[0] = [1, 2, 3]
sp[1] = [4, 5, 6]
```

То есть как сделать:

```
sp = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Comment: `N=3; sp = [sp[i:i+N] for i in range(0, N, len(sp))]`.

Answer (score 4):

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]  
     
n = 3
   
print([l[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(l), n)])
```

Answer (score 2):

Для Python 3.12+:

```py
from itertools import batched

sp = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

n = 3

print(list(batched(sp, n)))
```

---

[itertools.batched(iterable, n)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.batched)

Answer (score -1):

```
sp = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] 
print([l[i:i + 3] for i in range(0, len(sp), 3)])
```